# How to order javascript files in Drupal 7 to load Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7, zurb-foundation, drupal-theming

I try to load Foundation in my new "player" theme. It is a theme I make from scratch.
For now I am trying to load foundation.min.js in a preprocess :

```
function player_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {

  $options = array('scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 1000 );
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'player') . '/js/foundation.min.js', $options);
  $foundation='jQuery(document).foundation();';
  $options['type']='inline';
  drupal_add_js($foundation, $options);
}
```

When I load my site, I have two **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined** errors (once for the foundation.min.js, once for jQuery(document).foundation(); )

First I thought that is because jQuery is loaded after **jQuery(document).foundation();** but it seems default files, including jQuery, are loaded in the **header** (I did a var_dump to check.) And my script are laoded in the **footer**

```
  'misc/drupal.js'
  'misc/jquery.js'
  'misc/jquery.once.js'
  'sites/all/themes/player/js/theme.js'
  'sites/all/themes/player/js/uikit.js'
  'misc/jquery.cookie.js'
  'misc/jquery.form.js'
  'misc/progress.js'
  'misc/ajax.js'
  'misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js'
  'misc/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js'
  'misc/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js'
  'misc/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.min.js'
  'misc/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.min.js'
  'sites/all/modules/devel_themer/devel_themer.js'
  'sites/all/modules/devel/devel_krumo_path.js'
  'sites/all/modules/devel/krumo/krumo.js'
  'misc/jquery.ba-bbq.js'
  'modules/overlay/overlay-parent.js'
  'modules/toolbar/toolbar.js'
```

So I don't understand. It surely a common case but I don't find any help resource on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Load jquery first before anything else.

like so:

```
'misc/jquery.js'  // <---- move this up
'misc/drupal'
'misc/jquery.once.js'
'sites/all/themes/player/js/theme.js'
'sites/all/themes/player/js/uikit.js'
'misc/jquery.cookie.js'
'misc/jquery.form.js'
'misc/progress.js'
'misc/ajax.js'
'misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js'
'misc/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js'
'misc/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js'
'misc/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.min.js'
'misc/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.min.js'
'sites/all/modules/devel_themer/devel_themer.js'
'sites/all/modules/devel/devel_krumo_path.js'
'sites/all/modules/devel/krumo/krumo.js'
'misc/jquery.ba-bbq.js'
'modules/overlay/overlay-parent.js'
'modules/toolbar/toolbar.js'
```

Comment: How could I sort default scripts ?

Comment: Use the hook_js_alter and adjust the weight attributes for JS there.

Comment: Well, I tried with
function function player_js_alter(&$scripts){ 
 $scripts['misc/jquery.js']['weight']= -10000000;
}
But it shows the same error, and the chrome "Network tab in the developper tool shows me that foundation.min.js is  loaded before, event if its weight is 1000 ant it is in the footer.

Comment: Note that even if I use weight, when I open the source code jQuery is always behind foundation :
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/~fondcombe/danielneveux/sites/all/themes/player/js/foundation.min.js?njq8sh"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).foundation();
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/~fondcombe/danielneveux/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>`

Comment: Figure it out. I added the foundation scripts in the header and foundation seems to boot. But now I have another problem : undefined is not a function in jQuery... I will open another question for that.

PS : I don't know how to attribute the answer to Alberto.

Comment: (about my last problem with "undefined is not a function in jQuery) : use jQuery Update module in Drupal to fill the foudnation jquery requirement, and empty your cash (drush cc all).